# Iterated Coproduct in a Monoidal Category; finding the unit of a monoid.

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

Suppose $B$ is a monoidal category and further that the functors $-\bigotimes a:B\rightarrow B$ and $a\bigotimes -:B\rightarrow B$ preserve coproducts. The we have $\theta :\coprod _{b} a\bigotimes b_{n}\cong a\bigotimes \coprod _{n}b_{n}$, naturally in $a$, and similarly for the other functor.

If we apply these isomorphisms twice, we get

$\coprod _{m} a^{m}\bigotimes \coprod _{n} a^{n}\cong \coprod _{m}\left ( a^{m} \bigotimes \coprod _{n} a^{n}\right )\cong \coprod_{m} \left ( \coprod_{n} \left ( a^{m}\bigotimes a^{n} \right )  \right )$.

Actually the latter isomorphism $\coprod _{m} \theta $, isn't it ? After all, $\coprod $ is just a special type of limit functor. 
I want to find an explicit isomorphism between the latter coproduct and 
$\coprod _{n,m} a^{m}\bigotimes a^{n}$.

I need this to prove that $\eta  _{a}$, the unit of the monoid $\coprod _{n} a^{n}$ is given by the injection $i_{0}:e\rightarrow \coprod _{n} a^{n}$. I have $\mu $ and am trying to show that $\mu \circ (\eta \bigotimes 1)=\lambda $. All this works out very easily in $Set$ but I am having trouble with the general case.

Comment: So you want an explicit isomorphism $\coprod_m(\coprod_n(a^m\otimes a^n))\to \coprod_{n.m}a^m\otimes a^n$ ?

Comment: Well you can try and show that the former satisfies the same universal property as the latter. So let $f_{n,m}:a_{n,m}\to b$ be a family of maps, indexed over all pairs $(n,m)$, where $b$ and $a_{n,m}$ are any objects in your category. Then this gives you first a family of maps $f_m:\coprod_n a_{n,m}\to b$ indexed over all $m$, and this family then induces a map from $\coprod_m\coprod_n a_{n,m}$ to $b$. Uniqueness should follow pretty immediately.

Comment: @Stefan: Right. I did this and got the following coproduct:: $a^{n}\bigotimes a^{m}\overset{1_{a^{n}\bigotimes i_{m}}}{\rightarrow}a^{n}\bigotimes \coprod _{m}a^{m}\overset{i_{\left ( a^{n}\bigotimes \coprod _{m}a^{m} \right )}}{\rightarrow}\coprod _{n}\left ( a^{n}\bigotimes \coprod _{m}a^{m} \right )\overset{\coprod \theta }{\rightarrow}\coprod _{n}\left ( \coprod _{m}a^{n}\bigotimes a^{m} \right )$. So now I do have the isomorphism but I have not been able to use it to prove that $\eta $ is as advertised.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we take $\eta:e\to\coprod_n a^n$ to be the inclusion of $e=a^0$ into the coproduct. We want to show that $\mu(\eta\otimes1)=\lambda:e\otimes\coprod_n a^n\to\coprod_n a^n$. Consider the following commutative diagram

$$
\begin{matrix}
 & & e⊗∐_n a^n & → & ∐_m a^m⊗∐_n a^n & → & ∐_{m,n}a^m⊗a^n & → & ∐_k a^k \\
 & & \uparrow & & \uparrow & & \uparrow \\
e⊗a^n &\hookrightarrow & ∐_n e⊗a^n &→&∐_n(∐_m a^m)⊗a^n &→&∐_n∐_m(a^m⊗a^n)
\end{matrix}
$$

The arrow we are interested in is the upper path $\mu(\eta⊗1)$. I recommend you compose it with the arrow $1_e⊗i_n:e⊗a^n\to e⊗\coprod_n a^n$ and try to show that this is just $\lambda(1_e⊗i_n)$. Come back if you encounter problems.

---

Here is the solution: Composing the upper row with $1_e⊗i_n:e⊗a^n→e⊗∐_na^n$ gives the lower row augmented by the map $∐_n∐_m(a^m⊗a^n)→∐_k a^k$. The first two maps of the lower row compose to the map $\eta⊗1_{a^n}$. Composed with the third map, this gives $i_n\circ i_0:a^0⊗a^n \to ∐_m(a^m⊗a^n) \to ∐_n∐_m(a^m⊗a^n)$, which then composed with the upward arrow yields $i_{0,n}$. Composing with the last arrow produces the map $i_n\circ\lambda$, which by naturality of $\lambda$ is the same as $\lambda(1_e⊗i_n)$.

Comment: I don't see why the right hand square commutes. I fact, the upward arrow is precisely the one I was looking for an explicit fomula for. I also do not see how to work $\lambda $ into this diagram. Thanks.

Comment: @Chilango: The right hand square commutes by definition of the map 
$$μ:∐_m a^m⊗∐_n a^n → ∐_{m,n}a^m⊗a^n → ∐_k a^k$$
The first arrow in this composition is such that it makes the square commute. You can check this by comparing its inverse with the path going along the bottom for every summand $a^m⊗a^n$.

Comment: @Chilango: Also, I think an explicit formula for the isomorphism is not possible, unless you have a concrete category. You should just think of the arrow as the unique arrow which is induced by the UMP of the coproduct (making certain triangles commute).

Comment: By explicit formula, I just meant a more tractible expression for the arrows. For example, the upward arrows in the diagram are all isomorphisms defined through the UMP of the coproduct, as you say. For example, the second, call it $\theta $ is given by: $\theta \circ i_{_{\coprod _{m}a^{m}}\otimes a^{n}}=1_{\coprod _{m}a^{m}}\otimes i_{n}$. Now, if I compose the first two arrows on the upper path, I get $\eta \otimes 1_{\coprod _{n}a^{n}}$, not what you get.

Comment: After that, I compose the arrows using the isomorphisms $\theta $ and it gets very messy. I will work some more on this today but could you elaborate a little on your solution? By the way, the way I constucted the original diagram for $\mu $ the last horizontal arrow on top is a $\phi $ for which $\phi \circ i_{m,n}= i_{m+n}\circ can$, and in particular $\phi \circ i_{0,n}=i_{n}\circ \lambda _{a^{n}}$. Is this correct? $can$ is the canonical map given by the coherence theorem.

Comment: @Chilango: Sorry, there was a misunderstanding, by "this path" I meant the lower path. I changed the wording in my answer in order to remove any ambiguity.

Comment: Got it. Worked out perfectly! Thanks.